# When will an unsigned int variable becomes negative

Tags: c

I was going through the existing code and when debugging the UTC time which is declared as

`unsigned int utc_time;`

I could get some positive integer every time by which I would be sure that I get the time. But suddenly in the code I got a negative value for the variable which is declared as an unsigned integer.

Please help me to understand what might be the reason.

Comment: How are you debugging the code? printf?

Comment: Can you show us the offending code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unsigned integers, by their very nature, can *never* be negative.

You may end up with a negative value if you cast it to a signed integer, or simply assign the value to a signed integer, or even incorrectly treat it as signed, such as with:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    unsigned int u = 3333333333u;
    printf ("unsigned = %u, signed = %d\n", u, u);
    return 0;
}
```

which outputs:

```
unsigned = 3333333333, signed = -961633963
```

on my 32-bit integer system.

Comment: Or if you treat it as if it were signed, for example by printing it using `printf` with a `"%d"` format, which requires a (signed) int argument.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: The example was edited in just as Keith made the comment, good timing.

Answer (score 3):

When it's cast or treated as a `signed` type. You probably printed your `unsigned int` as an `int`, and the bit sequence of the `unsigned` would have corresponded to a negative `signed` value.

ie. Perhaps you did:

```
unsigned int utc_time;
...
printf("%d", utc_time);
```

Where `%d` is for `signed` integers, compared to `%u` which is used for `unsigned`. Anyway if you show us the code we'll be able to tell you for certain.

There's no notion of positive or negative in an `unsigned` variable.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you using

```
printf("%u", utc_time);
```

to display it

---

In response to the comment `%u` displays the varible as an unsigned int where as `%i` or `%d` will display the varible as a signed int.

Comment: 0pts - Add a description of what %u does and why it is necessary for an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Negative numbers in most (all?) C programs are represented as a [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) of the unsigned number plus one.  It's possible that your debugger or a program listing the values doesn't show it as an unsigned type so you see it's two's complement.

Comment: Certainly most, but no, not all :-)